# Create an 7zip archive in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, 7zip

I use this 7zip wrapper for Delphi 7 which works fine

https://github.com/zedalaye/d7zip

It creates archive but overwrites files already inside

```
var
  Arch: I7zOutArchive;
 begin
  Arch := CreateOutArchive(CLSID_CFormat7z);
  SetCompressionLevel(Arch, 2);
  Arch.AddFile('C:\Test.bin', 'Test.bin');
  Arch.SaveToFile('C:\Test.zip');
 end;
```

It removes all other files saved in 'Test.zip'
Is there anyway i can keep files inside 'Test.zip' and write new file with this wrapper in Delphi 7

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should first check if a file is already in the archive. If yes, do nothing, else add the file.

Comment: You dont have to vote down my question i did explained clearly that this method overwrites all files already inside archive i want to keep old files and add new inside.

Comment: Your "question" lacks an actual question. And my first comment answer the question you did'nt asked but more or less explained in your comment. btw: It is not me who down voted your question. Nevertheless, you should reformulate correctly with a QUESTION. Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wrapper you are using does not allow you to *update* an existing archive, only to *create* a new archive.  So, to *add* files to an existing archive, you would have to do the following:

- use `CreateInArchive()` to open the existing archive
- use `CreateOutArchive()` to create a new temp archive
- *copy* files from the input archive to the output archive
- *add* files to the output archive
- close both archives
- replace the old archive with the new archive

Comment: That's what i thought but was wondering maybe there is a direct way of doing it, thanks